# How can I combine two observables based on the result of the first observable?

Tags: rx-java, observable, rx-android

There are **3** observables, **2** of them can run sequentially, for example

```
Observable<BaseObject> baseObj = getBaseObs();

Observeable<Object1> obs1 = getObs1();
Observeable<Object2> obs2 = getObs2();
```

The `baseObj` should be executed first always, and if the result `baseObj.isFirst()` equals `true`, the observable `obs1` should be executed immediately, otherwise the `obs2` should be executed.

How can I combine two observables based on the result of the first observable?

Answer (score 1):

You can arrange for subsequent observables to be observed using the `switchMap()` operator:

```
baseObj
  .switchMap( isFirst -> isFirst ? obs1 : obs2 )
  .subscribe( ... );
```

The result of the observer chain is the result of either `obs1` or `obs2`, depending on `baseObj`.